# Get direct download link of magnet uri using webtorrent

Tags: javascript, html, webtorrent

How to stream videos from torrent file without downloading using WebTorrent.

**Here is my Code**

`<video id="video-container" controls="true"></video>`

`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webtorrent/latest/webtorrent.min.js"></script>`

var client = new WebTorrent();

  var torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=uid';



  client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {

    var file = torrent.files.find(function(file) {

       return file.name.endsWith('.mp4'); });

    var container = document.getElementById('video-container');

    file.renderTo(container);

  });

**I have tried this code but not rendering video to video tag**